# Compiling Emacs24 from git source

Tags: emacs

I've been using pre-releases of emacs for quite some time. I check out the code using git from `git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git` and follow the instructions in INSTALL.txt . The last time that worked fine was with 24.0.50.1 according to my emacs "about" screen. Since then I have periodically tried updating my emacs 24 version, but compilation always fails (possibly in the self-test or bootstrapping parts) with the following error:

```
Loading button (compiled; note, source file is newer)...
Loading startup (compiled; note, source file is newer)...
Loading /usr/local/src/emacs/lisp/loaddefs.el (source)...
Symbol's function definition is void: replace-buffer-in-windows
make[1]: *** [bootstrap-emacs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/emacs/src'
make: *** [src] Error 2
```

It's been like this for months. I've been googling regularly to see if there are any solutions/workarounds, but I find nothing. Am I the only one getting hit with this, and if so any suggestions for workarounds? It's not like I absolutely have to have the latest pre-release of emacs 24, but I would still like to figure out why I can no longer compile it, and why it seems nobody else is getting hit with the error (or aren't mentioning it anywhere where google can pick it up).

**Update:** This has happened on a Ubuntu 11.10 Desktop system, and now on the 12.04 betas, all x64.

Comment: What system are you trying to compile on? Any special compiler switches?

Comment: I just tested on an x64 Ubuntu server. `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make` spits out an emacs binary with no complaints.

Comment: try `git clean -xdf` to make sure get rid off old config.status and any other.

Comment: Also see [Minimal emacs24 installation on ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/a/1028960/173513) It provides instructions on building Emacs with a small footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning the latest version into a new directory, rather than doing an "in-place" pull (followed by `make distclean`, `./autogen.sh`, `./configure`, `make`) seems to solve it. So there has to be something left by earlier compilation processes for earlier versions that mess it up in my case.

So if you have similar problems, make sure you try a "clean" checkout into a fresh directory before giving up.

Comment: cloning again not good for the servers and git is smart to handle the your copy. `git clean -xdf`. by the way I pull from http://github.com/emacsmirror/emacs.git to avoid pressure on gnu servers

Comment: I'll give the git clean command a try. But just to be precise, I only cloned the first time, and then updated using pull.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. It seemed there were some old elisp compilation artifacts which were not being removed by `make clean`. I fixed it with

```
find . -name '*.elc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: Beware, you always want to use `print0` for `find` and `-0` for `xargs` to be safe, or even use `find … -exec rm -f '{}'`.