# Disable 2nd automatic Emacs nag message?

Tags: emacs

I built and installed Emacs 24.5 on a [Banana Pro](http://www.lemaker.org/product-bananapro-index.html). I basically followed [Minimal emacs24 installation](https://superuser.com/q/617468). It was my first time configuring and building Emacs from sources, and all the X, sound, mouse and image stuff was removed. It was done to free resources (its amazing how much uneeded junk is present in ***`emacs-nox`***).

I dismissed the first Emacs nag by setting ***`(setq inhibit-startup-message t)`*** in ***`.emacs`*** from [Unable to hide welcome screen in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/744672). However, it did not kill the second nag and I can't figure out how to disable it:

```
;; This buffer is for notes you don't want to save, and for Lisp evaluation.    
;; If you want to create a file, visit that file with C-x C-f,                  
;; then enter the text in that file's own buffer.
```

I'd *really* like Emacs to stop nagging me and allow me to get on to working.

How do I disable the second Emacs nag message?

Comment: **How do I change the scratch message in Emacs?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1498258/2112489

Comment: Thanks @lawlist. We can't close it as a dupe from another site, so you might as well answer and get the points. As far as I know, [Super User does not have the question](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This+buffer+is+for+notes+you+don%27t+want+to+save%2C+and+for+Lisp+evaluation.+%22+site:superuser.com) and its on-topic for Super User.